# cluster event bus consumer not getting the message

Tags: hazelcast, vert.x

I have two services(HttpServer and a Consumer) running on two different servers. 
I am using Hazelcast for clustering.

Here is my code :

```
public class SampleRestService extends StartVerticle {


@Override
public void start() {
   Router router = Router.router(vertx);
   router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
   router.post("/subscribe").handler(this::handleSubscription);
   vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(9001);
}

public void handleSubscription(RoutingContext routingContext) {
System.out.println("sending to event bus");
vertx.eventBus().send("myserviceadd", routingContext.request().path(), ar -> {
    if (ar.succeeded()) {
        //req.response().setStatusCode(200).write(result.result().body()).end();
        System.out.println("received response from event bus");
        routingContext.response().setStatusCode(200).end("myhttp-response" + ar.result().body() + " ** " + routingContext.request().path());
    } else if(ar.failed()) {
        System.out.println(" response from event bus is failed");
        ar.cause().printStackTrace();
        routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500).end("failed to subscribeS");
     }
 });
 }

}
```

Consumer Code :

```
public class SampleRestComsumer extends SampleConsumerParent {


 @Override
  public void start() {


  vertx.eventBus().consumer("myserviceadd", message -> {

        System.out.println("Recevied message: " + message.body());

        message.reply(new JsonObject().put("responseCode", "OK").put("message", "This is your response to your event"));

    });
 }

}
```

Here is my cluster.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config 
     hazelcast-config-3.2.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.wait.seconds.before.join">0</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">jdk</property>
    </properties>

    <group>
        <name>dev-test</name>
        <password>dev-pass</password>
    </group>
    <management-center enabled="false">http://localhost:8080/mancenter</management-center>
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="false" port-count="10000">5701</port>
        <outbound-ports>
            <!--
            Allowed port range when connecting to other nodes.
            0 or * means use system provided port.
            -->
            <ports>0</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false">
            <!--<multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>-->
            <!--<multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>-->
            </multicast>
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <!-- <interface>127.0.0.1</interface> -->
                <interface>10.27.92.45</interface>
                <interface>10.27.92.47</interface>
            </tcp-ip>
            <aws enabled="false">

            </aws>
        </join>
        <interfaces enabled="true">
            <interface>10.27.92.*</interface>
        </interfaces>        
    </network>
    <partition-group enabled="false"/>
    <executor-service name="default">
        <pool-size>16</pool-size>
        <!--Queue capacity. 0 means Integer.MAX_VALUE.-->
        <queue-capacity>0</queue-capacity>
    </executor-service>
    <map name="__vertx.subs">

        <!--
            Number of backups. If 1 is set as the backup-count for example,
            then all entries of the map will be copied to another JVM for
            fail-safety. 0 means no backup.
        -->
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>

        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
        <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
        <!--
            Valid values are:
            NONE (no eviction),
            LRU (Least Recently Used),
            LFU (Least Frequently Used).
            NONE is the default.
        -->
        <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
        <!--
            Maximum size of the map. When max size is reached,
            map is evicted based on the policy defined.
            Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means
            Integer.MAX_VALUE. Default is 0.
        -->
        <max-size policy="PER_NODE">0</max-size>
        <!--
            When max. size is reached, specified percentage of
            the map will be evicted. Any integer between 0 and 100.
            If 25 is set for example, 25% of the entries will
            get evicted.
        -->
        <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
        <merge-policy>
      com.hazelcast.map.merge.LatestUpdateMapMergePolicy
</merge-policy>
    </map>

    <!-- Used internally in Vert.x to implement async locks -->
    <semaphore name="__vertx.*">
        <initial-permits>1</initial-permits>
    </semaphore>

</hazelcast>
```

When i am running both the services. They are getting added to cluster and both services are up too but i am getting below error on server

```
 response from event bus is failed
 (TIMEOUT,-1) Timed out after waiting 30000(ms) for a reply. address: 
  7dfec6d2-3eaf-4006-90b1-6c2eaddb28bd
        at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.sendAsyncResultFailure(HandlerRegistration.java:118)
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.lambda$new$0(HandlerRegistration.java:65)
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you set cluster manager in your code, as explained in the documentation? https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-hazelcast/java

Comment: @AlexeySoshin yes i added the dependency in pom.

Comment: Adding dependency in POM is not enough. Do you also add cluster manager? `new VertxOptions().setClusterManager(mgr);`

Comment: @AlexeySoshin I have added this too.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong in the code snippets, so your servers might not actually be part of the cluster.